# Accessibility of radio buttons

Tags: html, css

Clicking on first and second value of radio button selects the first option.
HTML:

```css
  @supports(-webkit-appearance: none) or (-moz-appearance: none) {
  input[type='radio'],
  input[type='checkbox'] {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 1.5vw;
    width: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #ffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div class="radio-group">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Gender</legend>
    <label for="gender" id="gender-label">
        Male
        </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male">

    <label for="gender" id="gender-label">
        Female
        </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

SO is there any way to to make it so that when user clicks on "Female" the female radio button is checked?
Any help will be much appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Your IDs should be unique.

Comment: The issue is caused because you have an invalid HTML. You use an ID multiple times and it is no further unique. As such both labels address the same element (the first element with that ID).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="radio-group">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Gender</legend>
  <label for="male-for"
         class="gender-label">
    Male
    </label>
  <input type="radio"
         name="gender"
         id="male-for"
         value="male">

  <label for="female-for"
         class="gender-label">
    Female
    </label>
  <input type="radio"
         name="gender"
         id="female-for"
         value="female">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Your code should be like this.Your ids is not unique that's why it  is not working.If you have a design in style then you can change your `id="gender-label"` to
`class="gender-label"` .becuase  `id="gender-label"` writing same id is not valid

Comment: Your labels still have duplicate IDs ("gender-label") which is not valid html.

Comment: `<label for="male-for"
         id="male-label">
    Male
    </label>
  <input type="radio"
         name="gender"
         id="male-for"
         value="male">

  <label for="female-for"
         id="female-label">
    Female
    </label>`
Thanks @asgar . It works.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your ids. This code will work for you.

```
<label for="male" id="male-label">
        Male
</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">

<label for="female" id="female-label">
    Female
</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
```

Comment: Your labels still have duplicate IDs ("gender-label") which is not valid html.

Answer (score -1):

The ids must be uniques, this is how it should work:

```css
  @supports(-webkit-appearance: none) or (-moz-appearance: none) {
  input[type='radio'],
  input[type='checkbox'] {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 1.5vw;
    width: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #ffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div class="radio-group">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Gender</legend>
    <label for="genderMale" class="gender-label">
        Male
        </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderMale" value="male">

    <label for="genderFemale" class="gender-label">
        Female
        </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale" value="female">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: your ID's are still not all unique and your labels now adress elements that do not exist.